# Can't upsert data with external ID's using Data Loader

Tags: data-loader, upsert

Similar to this [question](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000A4GAIA0), I am not shown the [related object windows](https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Create-Parent-child-relationship-using-External-Id-in-Dataloader-624x328.png) to define what object the record is related to. I have tried manually editing the mappings but it always returns the same "Field mapping invalid" error.

Can someone explain why the screen is not being displayed?

Comment: Does the related object have an External ID field? That's a requirement in order for this to work.

Comment: It does indeed.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that the external ID sits in the Person Account object, as soon as I dropped the field into Account the extra screen is shown.